# JMSMessage content looped in Glassfish 4

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, java-ee-7

I've recently written some test code for the Java EE JMS API and have stumbled upon something that seems to be a bug to me.

The test is fairly simple: A CDI bean is connected to a JSF page and sends a predefinied `JMSMessage` to a `Queue`. There is an message-driven bean listening for messages on that `Queue` and it answers incoming messages in it's `onMessage` method.
Through another call from the JSF page the CDI bean tries to receive new messages synchronously and displays them to the frontend.

Here is the source:

MDB

```
@JMSDestinationDefinition(
    name = "java:app/jms/SomeQueue",
    interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue",
    destinationName = "SomeQueue")
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:app/jms/SomeQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class MyBean implements MessageListener {

@Inject
private JMSContext context;
@Resource
private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

@Resource(lookup = "java:app/jms/SomeQueue")
private Queue queue;

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    TextMessage tMessage = (TextMessage) message;
    try {
        context.createProducer().send(queue, tMessage.getText()+", Answer");
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        mdc.setRollbackOnly();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The CDI bean

```
@RequestScoped
@Named("jmssender")
public class JMSSender {

@Inject
private JMSContext context;

@Resource(lookup = "java:app/jms/SomeQueue")
private Queue queue;

@Inject
private UserTransaction utx;

private String answer;

private TextMessage message;


private int num;

public void sendMessage() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
        message = context.createTextMessage();
        String message = "This is message Nr. " + num;
        try {
            this.message.setText(message);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            message = "An error occurred";
        }
        context.createProducer().send(queue, message);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void receive() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
        answer = context.createConsumer(queue).receiveBody(String.class);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (NotSupportedException |
            SystemException |
            HeuristicRollbackException |
            RollbackException |
            HeuristicMixedException e) {
        answer = "Error receiving message";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
       ------getters and setters-----
```

The `num` property is used to identify each message send. I've used the `message` property to check whether my JMSMessages were send correctly.

**The Problem**

After having send a message, I try to receive the answer and see it in my frontend, it looks like this:

This is message Nr. 8 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0 Version 2.0

Apparently it loops the part of the string I enclosed to the original message, though when changing where exaclty in the code the additional String ", Answer" is added to the message, the message itself "this is message NR. X" is looped. Also it seems that how long the looped snippet is depends on how big the interval between pressing the "send" and the "receive" button is.

**If I only specify a string like "Hello" or just send the message back with tMessage.getText(), it works fine and doesn't loop any particular part**

Am I making the mistake or is it actually a bug?

**UPDATE**

-Deleted all uses of the UserTransaction interface (thought it might be needed to acknowledge messages in a CDI Bean) - didn't help

Comment: You are sending the message from the MDB to the same queue on which that MDB is listening? Should that not be another queue?

Comment: Makes sense :) I'll try it out. Also in general: do I need to manage the transaction in the web container for the message to be properly acknowledged?

Comment: Thanks for the help... You were right, I feel a bit emberessed about missing something that obvious. To correct way to implement a request/response mechanism would be to use temporary destinations, wouldn't it?